# How to deal with coworkers who don't want to give code reviews?

Tags: software-industry, software-development

Like most companies, my company has policy of requiring code reviews before you push code to a major git branch. If you want to push code to say the master branch or something, a person on your team has to review the code to make sure your logic is sound.

It seems like everyone on my team tries to avoid having to review my code or pull requests. One girl I asked said she doesn't know how to review code (despite being 7~8 years in the workforce). One guy said straight up, "Don't ask me"; did not give any reasoning and just left it at that. Others usually ignore any chat messages I give them asking for a code review. Sometimes, they'll give me code reviews if I ask them face to face since it is harder to come up with a legitimate excuse when someone asks you face to face.

Some context on my situation

- Some of those people have no problem asking me for help if there's something they don't know how to do or need help debugging an issue or something.
- Whenever they go out to lunch, they invite everyone on the team except me. This seems like a pretty big hint that they aren't really all that fond of me or at the very least, don't consider me part of the team. I don't feel that I've been a jerk or unpleasant to work with but perhaps I am as it is hard for any person to have the self awareness to know how they appear to other people.

Lately, I've been pushing code to the main repo without getting a code review. I probably can't keep doing that forever because if some code of mine ends up introducing a huge bug and they look back at the ticket and don't see any code review, I'll be to blame. What should I do?

Comment: Do other people get their code reviewed? It may just be a group thing, but if it's as a result of your behaviour, it might be wise to discuss this with a friend or family member (or maybe even a therapist), who might give you some insight as to what might be causing this and how you can improve. Your manager might also be able to tell you, if you have that sort of relationship. Your code reviews, when they do happen, your performance reviews or how your coworkers react if you ask questions may indicate if the problem lies with your work.

Comment: *they invite everyone on the team except me* - Ask if you can tag along some time.  It could be they think you are not interested in going to lunch with the team.

Comment: "Sometimes, they'll give me code reviews if I ask them face to face" - then do this. Say something like, "I'd like to push this code, but I need your help to review it first."

Comment: If the company policy says you shouldn't push without a review, why isn't this enforced in the repo? Also, why are you working on master? Branch out and work on that, then, after your review, merge on master. One more point, why isn't your manager doing the reviews himself?

Comment: @BgrWorker the team/technical leader or project manager I suppose ? It's possible that the manager is not technical and so can't handle code reviews.

Comment: Does your team have a daily standup? This definitely sounds like a **block**.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Stop pushing un-reviewed code **immediately**.

You are deliberately disobeying company policy and they could absolutely fire you for it.

Then, **talk to your manager**. Stick to the facts that impact your *work* (You can't commit your code, because nobody on the team is available to review it.). Then let them handle it, that's their job.

Absolutely *do not* make any kind of speculation to your boss about *why* your coworkers might not have time for your code reviews, just stick to the facts.

Separately, yes, it does sound a lot look there is a group here, and you are currently on the outside of it. Unfortunately, unless you have a good handle on *why* that is, there's not much advice I can offer there, other than to continue being professional and doing good work, and seeing what happens once your manager gets involved.

Comment: Considering that they're not doing code reviews and don't seems to care that much vs someone that does. That's sound like a starting point of why they don't like him. And talking to your manager if it may enforce the code reviews may however worsen the relationship with his teammates.

Answer (score 10):

Solution is fairly simple, don't whine about it to the manager or confront people. Or beat about the bush etc,. Just do it professionally.

Email a polite request for a code review with your manager cc'd. If no reply follow up politely with your manager cc'd. Just keep doing that. If it continues to get ignored, then you email your manager that you need a code review, everyone seems to be busy and if he/she could organise it for you.. Always keep a clear paper trail covering your back with the manager involved.

And stop pushing code against company policy.

Comment: always cover your back. That's the most important.